# Convert String Date to Unix TimeStamp Sqlite3

Tags: sql, sqlite, datetime, date-arithmetic

I've to copy a column in another column, but the result is that only the first row is copied and put in all the rows of the other column

I'm trying to execute this query:

```
UPDATE gdf_storico Set Data = (SELECT Giorno FROM timestamp)
```

But that stores the same date in all columns

Comment: You can do period queries already, you don't need to change the storage format. SQLite [has no types](https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html) and dates can be stored as text, reals or integers with text in ISO8601 being the *easiest* to query. Date functions work on any format

Comment: What is the actual problem? Why do you think you need to change the storage format? Text in ISO8601 form is *easier* to use for date and period queries than integers, which is what you probably mean by `unix timestamp`. If you want all dates in December 2020, you search for `mydate between '2020-12-01' and '2020-12-31'`. Or even `mydate like '2020-12-%'`

Comment: *Clients* on the other hand *do* have date types, they don't use raw integers. Java, C#, JavaScript, Python, Go, all have date types

Comment: and if I want the Min date of the db? How can i search it?

Comment: The same way you always do. What's the question? Have you encountered an actual problem or just assumed there would be a problem? Have you checked [the docs on types](https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html)? `SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates and/or times. Instead, the built-in Date And Time Functions of SQLite are capable of storing dates and times as TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER values`. Using integers has no benefit over using text as far as SQLite is concerned

Comment: The [date and time functions](https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) return text too. `The date() function returns the date in this format: YYYY-MM-DD. The time() function returns the time as HH:MM:SS.`

Comment: Okay, but how can i search the minimum date of my db? I know how to do with timestamp because it's an integer, but with string?

Comment: The same. Using the same aggregate functions like `min` or `max`. Other functions make no sense for dates no matter how they're stored - you can't sum or average dates

Comment: Seriously, what's the question here? What's the problem to solve?

Comment: Actually I've the problem to copy the column from a table to another. UPDATE gdf_storico Set Data = (SELECT Giorno FROM timestamp). I try like that but it copies the first date to all the column while if you run only the SELECT in () are showed all the dates

Comment: Edit your question, add your code and explain your actual problem. What you posted works as intended - it will set all rows to the same value. If you wanted to copy dates, the problem is the query, not the type. Even if you cast to integer, you'll still get the first date only - assuming you don't get a runtime error because you tried to store multiple values in a single cell

Comment: Post sample data of both tables and explain what you want to do.

Comment: Hi, I've a column with dates like YYYY-MM-DD and I want to copy this values in another column, just created in another table

Answer (score 1):

In SQLite, you can use `strftime()` with modifier `'%s'` to convert a date to an epoch timestamp:

```
select datecol, strftime('%s', datecol) as unix_ts
from mytable
```

Comment: I try and I say u if work

Comment: @GianniMirabello what's the actual problem? You don't need to change the storage format to perform period queries. SQLite has no types, just storage formats. Date/period queries work with *any* of the formats supporting dates